# ios - Moving swift files to Modern frameworks but losing Flurry Analytics functionality

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, flurry

I am adding in modern frameworks so I can use my existing code on a share extension. The links on stackOverflow have been great but do not address how to maintain Flurry analytics in those models moved into the frameworks.

I have the models in the new framework working no problem except some of those models had flurry log events.   I am getting 'use of unresolved identifier, Flurry' as an error message.

I would like to continue using flurry in these events if possible but not clear on how to link my new library named "V2Core" to the Flurry Framework.

FYI.   Flurry was working great prior to moving these files to the new framework.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Since I did not receive any feedback I am curious if I asked the question the wrong way?

Comment: I don't think you asked the wrong way, I think it's that no one has an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the "use of unresolved identifier, Flurry" error message when I accidentally introduced a circular dependency into my frameworks. Framework 'A' has Flurry.logEvent() calls and Framework 'B' also has Flurry.logEvent() calls. Framework 'A' included an "import B", but originally Framework 'B' was standalone and everything worked fine. The moment I introduced "import A" into Framework 'B', the "use of unresolved identifier, Flurry" error message popped up. If your code uses (or you can successfully introduce into your code) a variable of type FlurryEventRecordStatus and you can compare it to FlurryEventFailed in the same place as "use of unresolved identifier, Flurry" without Xcode complaining, that would be a tell-tale sign that you have a circular dependency, rather than Flurry just not being integrated into your build properly.